# OpenSSL or such without Command Line

Tags: ssl, encryption, ssh, openssl

I want to implement OpenSSL or something such but my problem is that I neither have Command Line Interface to my Linux Server nor access to Admin Panel. I can't access any other folder except where my website resides because I am using FTP.

The website is at `http://www.swamisantdass.com`. It will be updated soon so I want to implement SSL.

I may be getting OpenSSL wrong (I don't know)

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It appears there is no HTTPS server at `www.swamisantdass.com`. `openssl s_client -connect www.swamisantdass.com:443 -servername www.swamisantdass.com -tls1` times out after the TCP handshake.

Comment: OK, thanks, will upgrade my service plans soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want HTTPS, so your website would be accessible via  http**s**://www.swamisantdass.com ? That's web server configuration and only server administrator can enable that, but you should provide him SSL certificate.